# Spoiler markup is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Spoiler alert code on [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15054/in-the-dune-series-why-did-the-2000-special-edition-version-by-frank-herbert-no) is not working, also on meta:

> Spoiler alert is not working

Comment: all.css has #888 as the spoiler colour, but the background is #222. I get #E8F2EB for both on the main site, so either it's fixed there or I'm getting a cached version.

Comment: I fixed the markup on your question. there were embedded newline characters after each line. Did you copy paste that text, by chance?

Comment: Spoilers work for me on the main site, but the colors on meta are still contrasting (not sure what would need to be spoilered here though).

Comment: I [asked this before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/spoiler-styling-in-meta-doesnt-effectively-hide-spoilers) and it was fixed... but somehow it got un-fixed.

Comment: I like this bug a lot.

Comment: Is this broken again on main? Specifically on my answer at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21289/4025

Comment: @MarkBeadles Looks fine to me, I only see it on mouseover

Answer (score 3):

My spoiler markup wasn't working either, but turns out that you can't spoiler multiple paragraphs

This markup...

```
>! spoiler paragraph 1

>! spoiler paragraph 2
```

looks like this...

> ! spoiler paragraph 1
>
> ! spoiler paragraph 2

I had to be remove the intervening actual blank line, and append `<br><br>` to synthetically insert it again

> spoiler paragraph 1
>  spoiler paragraph 2

The raw text now looks like...

```
>! spoiler paragraph 1<br><br>
>! spoiler paragraph 2
```

Comment: You can do multi-line spoilers without HTML markup, but it's not intuitive: [example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147871/149432), [source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/fceb6e1c-2cc4-4348-adbb-0988cf10e7f7/view-source)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the spoiler tags are working on either SFF or Meta. If I'm mistaken, correct me, but I thought spoiler tags looked like this:

>
! SPOILERS GO HERE < br > < br >

Without the spaces, of course. I tried to test the spoiler tag on SFF and it wouldn't work for me. And I can see the text of your spoiler message as grey against dark grey. When I mouse over it, it turns white. But it's definitely not hidden for me (and I'm talking about your meta post here)

> THIS IS WITHOUT THE SPACES IN THE CODE AND I'LL BET YOU CAN SEE THE TEXT, YES?

Hopefully someone will have the magic answer!

Answer (score 1):

I can repro this bug on meta but not on main. I pushed a fix for the meta spoiler text. It will be in the next production build.